# How to validate a certificate chain that its CA certificate and intermediate certificate are only available online

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I'm trying to validate a certificate chain which a part of it is offline certificate files and another part (Root CA and intermediates certificates) is online.

My chain consists of 7 certificates, Last 4 certificates in the chain are stored offline and the 3 certificates which include one root CA and 2 intermediates are stored online.

The 4th certificate (first one offline) has the URI to the remote certificate, I want to validate the whole chain from leaf to root, I tried using X509Chain.Build() method but I keep getting PartialChain error.

I prefer using .Net libraries only, but a correct solution using bouncy-castle libraries is welcome as well.

Notes:

- I don't mind getting an untrusted-root error since the root is not installed locally on my machine and that's how I want it to be.
- The 4 certificates stored offline are simple files, not installed certificates, again, this is on purpose.

```
public static bool VerifyCertificateChain(ArrayList certChain, byte[] leaf)
{
    X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck; // not checking revocation for now

    // Here I add all offline certificates
    foreach(byte[] cert in certChain)
    {
        chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(new X509Certificate2(cert));
    }

    bool ret = chain.Build(new X509Certificate2(leaf));

    // Always false for me
    if(!ret)
    {
        // Here I get PartialChain status even though the chain is complete
        foreach(X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(status.ToString() + " - " + status.StatusInformation);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I expect the Build method to return true, or maybe return false with untrusted-root status but why do I get PartialChain status?

Comment: What does it mean here *stored online*? Or rather, isn't it possible to download these so that they are available for the chain validation?

Comment: I guess it's possible to download them, but I think .Net's X509Chain.Build method can do the job automatically.

Comment: I just remember similar issue, not remember actual details but I remember we ended up having the whole chain available to the `Build` and it just works.

Comment: How many chain elements does it end up with? Does the first http (not https) AIA URL from the last element work for an unauthenticated, no-redirect GET?

Comment: *My chain consists of 7 certificates* Are you serious? That's the longest chain I've ever heard of. Has to be some military organization, right?